# How to store the uri of image from registerForActivityResult() and send it to another function

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

The image i've selected from gallery disappear after the configuration changes, so i wanted to get the uri of the image so i can pass it to onSaveInstanceState but i don't know how to do so.

```
val selectImageFromGalleryResult = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
        uri?.let {
            profileImage.setImageURI(uri)
        }
    }

    selectBtn.setOnClickListener {
        profileImage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        selectImageFromGalleryResult.launch("image/*")
    }
```

If i create a global variable,

```
private lateinit var imageUri: Uri
```

i get error saying it has not been initialized if i get the value from the above function and try to send it to onSaveInstanceState

Comment: Have you used `ViewModel`?

Comment: I haven't and also i am a beginner so i have no idea what does that mean, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Uri` is `Parcelable` itself, you can directly put it into the `Bundle`. To help with saving it to state, you may need to create member variable in your activity

```
private var profileImageUri: Uri? = null
```

and once you obtain Uri from `ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()`, then store it in `profileImageUri`

```
val selectImageFromGalleryResult = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
        uri?.let {
            profileImageUri = uri
            profileImage.setImageURI(uri)
        }
    }
```

and save this `profileImageUri` in `Bundle` at `onSaveInstanceState()`

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle, outPersistentState: PersistableBundle) {
    outState.putParcelable("profileImageUri", profileImageUri)
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState)
}
```

and to make sure on configuration change the image view load the uri, put below code in your `onCreate()` function

```
profileImageUri = savedInstanceState?.getParcelable("profileImageUri")
profileImageUri?.let {
    profileImage.setImageURI(it)
}
```

Additional: if you use `ViewModel`, it will give you more concise way. Just can create an object to save the `Uri` in the `ViewModel` and no longer need to create boilerplate code above to survive the `Uri` on configuration changes